# What's the standard way for getting uniformly distributed random integers in C++?

Tags: c++, random

Is there a function for obtaining *uniformly* distributed pseudo-random integers in some specified range? I could write my own function using `rand`, but this seems like a common enough situation that there's probably something in the STL for it.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[Boost](http://www.boost.org/) provides many tools for random number generation.
For uniform distributions you have this one:

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/doc/html/boost/random/uniform_real_distribution.html

**EDIT:** updated to include the new C++11 implementation. For the case of integers, here you have the reference:

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_int_distribution

A simple example would be:

```
#include <random>
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    std::random_device rd;
    std::mt19937 gen(rd());
    std::uniform_int_distribution<> dis(1, 6);
    for(int n=0; n<10; ++n)
        std::cout << dis(gen) << ' ';
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

Comment: And they are now part of **C++11** so they are standard.

Comment: @K-ballo that's great! C++11 is making C++ much easier :)

Answer (score 10):

To generate pseudo-random numbers in C++, a very good option is using the **[Mersenne twister](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_twister) pseudo-random number generator engine**: **`std::mt19937`** from the `<random>` header.

We can think of this **engine** as a *black-box* that spits out *high-quality random bits*.

Then, these random bits can be *shaped* in some integers output using a **distribution**; in particular, to get *uniformly distributed* pseudo-random numbers, a **`std::uniform_int_distribution`** can be used.

Note that the engine object must be initialized with a *seed*.
`std::random_device` can be used for that purpose.

So, this process can be summarized in three logical steps:

1. Create an instance of `std::random_device`, to get a *non-deterministic seed* for the Mersenne twister engine.
2. Create an instance of `std::mt19937` *engine*, to get high-quality pseudo-random bits.
3. Use a `std::uniform_int_distribution` to *shape* these random bits in *uniformly-distributed integers*.

Compilable C++ code follows:

```
#include <iostream>     // for console output
#include <random>       // for pseudo-random number generators and distributions

int main()
{
    // Use random_device to generate a seed for Mersenne twister engine.
    std::random_device rd;    

    // Use Mersenne twister engine to generate pseudo-random numbers.
    std::mt19937 engine(rd());
    
    // "Filter" MT engine's output to generate pseudo-random integer values,
    // **uniformly distributed** on the closed interval [0, 99].  
    // (Note that the range is [inclusive, inclusive].)
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> dist(0, 99);

    // Generate and print 10 pseudo-random integers
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    {
        std::cout << dist(engine) << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

---

For more details on generating pseudo-random numbers in C++ (including reasons why `rand()` is *not* good), see this video by *Stephan T. Lavavej* (from [Going Native 2013](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013)):

> [`rand()` Considered Harmful](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/rand-Considered-Harmful)

Comment: +1 It sure took a while but this was finally merged. You may want to edit your question to indicate that it was part of a merge and a comment to the OP as well so they understand why this new answer popped up with an old date.

Comment: I don't know why everyone say that Mersenne Twister is so great and "high-quality". It's not. It is complicated, has an enormous memory footprint and still fails multiple tests of the TestU01 BigCrush test suite. There are several simpler, faster and much higher quality PRNGs today with adequate periods.

Comment: @plasmacel: I asked Stephan T. Lavavej (VC STL maintainer) and he confirmed its the best standard PRNG. What would you propose as better alternatives?

Answer (score 0):

To generate one or specified number of random variables with uniform distribution on integer domain using `std::generate_n` and `boost`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <boost/random.hpp>

/*
 * 
 */
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    boost::mt19937 rand_generator(std::time(NULL));
    boost::random::uniform_int_distribution<> int_distribution(0, 100);

    //Need to pass generator
    std::cout << int_distribution(rand_generator) << std::endl;

    //Associate generator with distribution
    boost::random::variate_generator<boost::mt19937&,
            boost::random::uniform_int_distribution<>
            > int_variate_generator(rand_generator, int_distribution);

    //No longer need to pass generator
    std::cout << int_variate_generator() << std::endl;
    std::generate_n( std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, ","), 3, int_variate_generator);
    return 0;
}
```