# Random number generator keeps creating 2

Tags: c++, random

I am using

```
#include<conio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
```

to generate a random number from 1-10.

the code is:

```
rando = rand() % 10 + 1;
```

for some reason 2 keep being generated. Is there something wrong with my phrasing?

Comment: How did you call `srand()`?

Comment: Why is 2 not random for you?

Comment: Have you called `srand()` anywhere in your program?

Comment: Well it's consistently 2, nothing else. Also when I change the `rand() % 10 + 1;` to `rand() % 10 +2;` It consistently generates 3.

Comment: No I have only called `rand()`

Comment: Can't resist: http://dilbert.com/dyn/str_strip/000000000/00000000/0000000/000000/00000/2000/300/2318/2318.strip.gif

Comment: BTW, with C++11, you are encouraged to use `<random>` facilities instead.

Comment: Show compilable code that reproduces the problem. Otherwise we are just guessing.

Comment: You shouldn't use `rand()` in C++11 and newer. You may want to [read this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22022099/1629821) for more details.

Comment: @Jarod42 By whom?  The two facilities are different, and address different uses.  For just playing around, games and homework, `rand()` is generally sufficient; the extra complexity of `<random>` is really only justified for serious analytics.

Comment: @Thirler, maybe nine is [guaranteed to be random](http://xkcd.com/221/) as well.

Comment: @JamesKanze: `std::uniform_int_distribution` seems more simple and intuitive than (biaised) `rand() % 10 + 1`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why do I always get the same sequence of random numbers with rand()?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1108780/why-do-i-always-get-the-same-sequence-of-random-numbers-with-rand)

Comment: @Jarod42 Have a look at the examples in some of the answers, and tell me that they aren't overly complicated.  (If you need a non-uniform distribution, or if you need some sort of guaranteed quality of the random numbers, the new versions win out, because getting either with the old `rand()` requires a _lot_ of extra code.  But for a lot of simple projects, having to create instances of three different types is just excess complexity.)

Answer (score 4):

To generate random nuber from 1 to 10, you should really use `rand() % 10 + 1`
but firstly needed initialization of random seed, look at example:

```
  #include <stdio.h>      /* printf, NULL */
  #include <stdlib.h>     /* srand, rand */
  #include <time.h> 

  int iSecret ;

  /* initialize random seed: */
  srand (time(NULL));

  /* generate secret number between 1 and 10: */
  iSecret = rand() % 10 + 1;
```

Comment: **Note:** unless you know *why* you're doing otherwise, `srand()` should be invoked **once** for the lifetime of your process. Do **not** cut/paste *all* of the code in this answer into a single function you're expecting to call repeatedly.

Comment: usually initialization calls once in programm

Answer (score 3):

If you're using C++ 11 you can consider using `<random>` header (you also have to seed the random engine):

```
#include <random>

std::random_device rd;
std::default_random_engine dre(rd());

std::uniform_int_distribution<int> uid(1,10);

int number = uid(dre);
```

Answer (score 0):

1) You shouldn't use `rand()`, it has bad distribution, short period etc...

2) You shouldn't use `%x` when `MaxValue % x != 0` because you mess your uniform distribution (suppose you don't use rand()), e.g. `32767 % 10 = 7` so number 0-7 are more likely to get

Watch this for more info: [Going native 2013 -  Stephan T. Lavavej - rand() Considered Harmful](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/rand-Considered-Harmful)

You should use something like:

```
#include <random>

std::random_device rdev;
std::mt19937 rgen(rdev());
std::uniform_int_distribution<int> idist(0,10); //(inclusive, inclusive)
```

I in my codes use something like this:

```
template <typename T>
T Math::randomFrom(const T min, const T max)
{
    static std::random_device rdev;
    static std::default_random_engine re(rdev());
    typedef typename std::conditional<
        std::is_floating_point<T>::value,
        std::uniform_real_distribution<T>,
        std::uniform_int_distribution<T>>::type dist_type;
    dist_type uni(min, max);
    return static_cast<T>(uni(re));
}
```

NOTE: the implementation is not thread safe and constructs a distribution for every call. That's inefficient. But you can modify it for your needs.

Comment: Re point 1: it depends on what you're doing.  For serious analytic work (Monte Carlo evaluations and such), you shouldn't use `rand()`.  For just playing around and games, `rand()` is generally sufficient, and a lot simpler.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you didn't initialize the seed for `rand()`, i.e. you didn't call [`srand()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/srand/) (in the usual old form of `srand(time(NULL))`), so you get the same number sequence.

But, anyway, you *should not* use `rand()` in C++11 and newer.
You may want to use `std::mt19937` and `std::uniform_int_distribution` instead.

You may want to [read this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22022099/1629821) for more details.
(I'm not going to duplicate the code and answer text here).